# es-lint is throwing a warning for ```There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.``` for node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, eslint

I checked all my import statements and they seem to be fine, the only odd import I have is react-bootstrap and I import it as

`import { Jumbotron, Button  } from 'react-bootstrap';`

to use the Jumbotron and button, not sure what else to do.

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
backend.js:6 ../frontEnd/node_modules/process/browser.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\index.js
* C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontend\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults.js
r @ backend.js:6
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:137
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:142
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:209
backend.js:6 ../frontEnd/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontEnd\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image_Uploader\frontend\node_modules\gud\index.js
r @ backend.js:6
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:137
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:142
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:209
```

my file names [image]

Comment: How about class or file names within your project?

Comment: I think they are pretty unique, I attached photo

Answer (score 0):

The error was, when I cd into the folder i did `cd frontend` but the folder name is `frontEnd` , so be careful of your casing :D

you can see the error in the output log, but its hard to see it if you are not looking for it.